# How to handle comma delimiter when they are part of the data and without quotes to load to hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

Have text file with comma separated fields where one field has comma within it but not quoted, example given below.

```
u'22', datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1),u'text'
```

All reference included about serde where we can use it if the delimiter is within quotes, but for me its not. I am using hive to load it and tried with serde as well. How to deal with this data, pls suggest

Comment: Use regex to replace commas you don't want with something else.  Are all unwanted commas inside ()?

Comment: yes actually those needs to be combined as one datetime... how to use regex while loading csv to hive? my file size is huge more than few gbs.

Comment: @D14, try changing your delimiter to | or ^ instead of comma